# F8 acting like F5 when I change operating system (Windows XP - Windows 7)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have an odd problem when debugging a macro in Excel VB (Excel 2010).  When I use the "F8" key to skip through the code in Windows XP (my old operating system) it works fine.  However when I use "F8" to skip through the same macro in Windows 7 it acts like "F5" after a few lines.  Clearly it must be something to do with a setting or the environment but I can't figure it out?  Has anyone come across this before and know a possible solution?

Thanks,

Ciaran.

Comment: The title makes it sound like an operating system question but it's actually an Excel development question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI - I went onto the microsoft website and downloaded the latest VB/Excel service packs for Excel 2010 and that resolved my issue.